# How to connect a domain name to a host?

Tags: dns, domain, hosts, bind

I have register a domain on internet like `domain.com`. I have a server on internet which have installed bind9 service on it.

I have enter my name server on DNS tools on my provider domain name manager panel as an `A record` like `n1.site.com` and `ns2.site.com`.

What should i do to connect that domain to my host myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the domain registered with a domain host service or provider or whatever you call them. Godaddy and Networksolutions are examples. That provider should have a DNS tool where you can set an A record for the domain, that points to the IP address of the server. If the provider does not offer this service, move you domain to another provider that does, or ask them to set the DNS. I prefer if I can do this myself, and most providers offer this service for free.

Comment: You should leave the nameservers like they are (ns1, ns2), unless you have a good reason to move them. This can be useful when you have a high traffic site hosted at another location or provider. For you it won't matter I guess. You should add two A records for domain.com and www.domain.com to the IP address of your webserver.

Comment: +1, for your answer and your pursuit. I want to know even i got your idea or not; you mean if i just set my server IP address on domain dns panel everything OK and not need to configure anything on my server?

Comment: You have to setup a webserver (including databaseserver, PHP or other languages if needed), configure firewall, setup port forwarding in the router if it is located at home or at work (to route incoming traffic to the server). And that's what I think of now. It depends on what you want, what OS you run on the server etc. I guess that's another question?!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your domain name to point to your server, you need to update the A record

So, the A record should point to an IP address (unless the domain name you enter is correctly set up of course)

The MX is for email.

I *normally* leave the others alone.

However, if you've updated n1.site.com (often called glue records) from the original value then you'll have to set up the DNS yourself on your server.

Comment: Thank you. I sereach an read about it too many. Now I think i have to set up DNS on myself server. Note that my server have installed bind9 service and have configured for another domain. Now i need to configure it for my own domain.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand :(  Personally, I'd reset the values back to what they are (your registrar should have this information on their site). Then, try to update only the A record and enter the IP address of your server.